# Form data not being sent in POST

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have started a Spring MVC app that also uses JQuery. I'm just working out the details of user management and have gotten most of the way through but I'm having a little difficulty on the page that allows editing of user data. There are two forms on the page. The first allows an admin to select a user to edit. It properly makes an Ajax call that populates the second form with that user's data. When the second form is submitted a default (empty) object is returned to the back-end.

When I examine the value of selectedUser or the Model in the postUser method the object is a default (empty) one. I don't see the data that was populated on in the jsp before the submit. 
Here is my full jsp and the back-end method that receives the POST:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Update roles</title>
      <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

    // This is just a placeholder for now. I might want to preprocess some data 
    // before submitting.
    $("#updateUserForm").submit(function(event) {
        alert("selectedUser.username=" + $('[name="username"]').val());
    });

    // This is for selecting a user from the list and then populating
    // the other form with it.
    $("#selectUserForm").submit(function(event) {
        //get the form data and then serialize that
        dataString = $("#selectUserForm").serialize();

        //get the form data using another method 
        var userId = $("#userSelect").val();

        //make the AJAX request, dataType is set to json
        //meaning we are expecting JSON data in response from the server
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "getUser/" + userId,

            //if received a response from the server
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('body').empty();
                $('body').html(data);
            },

            //If there was no resonse from the server
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error: " + textStatus);
                console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                $("#ajaxResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
            },

            //capture the request before it was sent to server
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
                //disable the button until we get the response
                $('#selectUserBtn').attr("disabled", true);
            },

            //this is called after the response or error functions are finsihed
            //so that we can take some action
            complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //enable the button 
                $('#selectUserBtn').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function addRole() {
          alert("in addRole");  
        }

        function removeRole() {
          alert("in removeRole");
        }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Update User</h1>
        </div>
        <form:form id="selectUserForm" modelAttribute="selectUserData">
            <fieldset>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><form:select id="userSelect" style="width:125px"
                                path="userList">
                        <c:forEach items="${selectUserData.userList}" var="userList">
                            <option value="${userList.id}">${userList.displayName}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form:select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="selectUserBtn" type="submit"
                    value="Select User" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
<hr>
<form:form method="POST" id="updateUserForm" action="updateUser" modelAttribute="selectUserData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.username">Username</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input name="username" path="selectedUser.username"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="selectedUser.firstName"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="selectedUser.lastName"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.password">Password</form:label></td>
            <td><form:password path="selectedUser.password"></form:password></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="selectedUser.email"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.authorities">Authorities</form:label></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><form:select id="availableRoles" path="availableRoles"
                                style="width:175px;" multiple="true">
                                <c:forEach items="${selectUserData.availableRoles}"
                                    var="availableRole">
                                    <option value="${availableRole}">${availableRole}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select></td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="button" id="addRoleBtn" onclick="addRole();" value="&gt;&gt"></input><br>
                                        <input type="button" id="removeRoleBtn" onclick="removeRole();" value="&lt;&lt;"></input></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td><form:select id="authorities"
                                path="selectedUser.authorities" style="width:175px"
                                multiple="true">
                                <c:forEach items="${selectUserData.selectedUser.authorities}"
                                    var="authority">
                                    <option value="${authority}">${authority}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.accountNonExpired">Account non-expired</form:label></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="selectedUser.accountNonExpired"></form:checkbox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.accountNonLocked">Account non-locked</form:label></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="selectedUser.accountNonLocked"></form:checkbox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.credentialsNonExpired">Credentials non-expired</form:label></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="selectedUser.credentialsNonExpired"></form:checkbox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="selectedUser.enabled">Enabled</form:label></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="selectedUser.enabled"></form:checkbox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="updateUserBtn" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<div id="anotherSection">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Response from jQuery Ajax Request</legend>
        <div id="ajaxResponse"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

And here's my backend method:

```
      @Controller
      @RequestMapping("/admin")
      public class UserAdminController {
      ...
            @RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            @Secured({"ADMIN"})
            public ModelAndView postUser(@ModelAttribute("selectUserData") User selectedUser, Model model) {
                UserData userData = new UserData();
                List<Map<String, String>> userList = userService.getUserList();
                userData.setUserList(userList);
      userData.setSelectedUser((User)model.asMap().get("selectUserData"));
            return new ModelAndView("/admin/updateUser", "selectUserData", userData);
        }
```

In repsonse to Minion's question, here is a snippet of the value of the data variable returned in the Ajax call:

> ```
>      <form id="updateUserForm" action="updateUser" method="POST">
>         <table>
>           <tr>
>             <td><label for="selectedUser.username">Username</label></td>
>             <td><input id="selectedUser.username" name="selectedUser.username" type="text" value="user"/></td>
>           </tr>
>           <tr>
>             <td><label for="selectedUser.firstName">First Name</label></td>
>             <td><input id="selectedUser.firstName" name="selectedUser.firstName" type="text" value="user"/></td>
>           </tr>
>           <tr>
>             <td><label for="selectedUser.lastName">Last Name</label></td>
>             <td><input id="selectedUser.lastName" name="selectedUser.lastName" type="text" value=""/></td>
>           </tr>
>           <tr>
>             <td><label for="selectedUser.password">Password</label></td>
>             <td><input id="selectedUser.password" name="selectedUser.password" type="password" value=""/></td>
>           </tr>
>           <tr>
>             <td><label for="selectedUser.email">Email</label></td>
>             <td><input id="selectedUser.email" name="selectedUser.email" type="text" value="dm_tim@yahoo.com"/></td>
>           </tr>
> ```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` requires argument named `event`, you have argument `e`

Comment: What is with the `<form:form ` ?

Comment: If the problem is with the clientside code, could we just have that instead?

Comment: I see you are doing $('body').html(data);. Is the data evaluated HTML or does it have form:form etc? Can you post a snippet of the data returned.

Comment: is the value of the variable selectedUser  received in the controller postUser  method null?

Comment: to match your code would need to be `e.preventDefault()`. Using `event` will throw undefined error and won't stop form submitting through browser default process, which is likely happening. Change variable to match argument in handler function

Comment: see example of `e` vs `event`  http://jsfiddle.net/3kjpfjcq/1

Comment: @TRGWII, those are spring tags. Sorry, I just put a spring-mvc tag on my original post, I did not put it in the subject line. Also, the client is the jsp above (and I believe that the issue may very well be in there), was there something other than that that you wanted?

Comment: @charliefl, My bad. I actually needed one of those preventDefault calls. I see what you're referring to. I did change the parameter from e to event, however the problem persists. On the back end I'm still seeing blank objects. Good catch though.

Comment: Like i asked earlier, can you provide a snippet of rendered html page. I guess something is going wrong in $('body').html(data) where data that you are adding is not in a proper way.

Comment: @Paul John, the value of selectedUser is a blank representation of the object I was expecting back: {id : null, username : null, firstName : null, lastName : null, password : null, accountNonExpired : false, accountNonLocked : false, credentialsNonExpired : false, enabled : false}

Comment: @minion, that was an interesting idea. The returned value for data was straight html, there were no spring tags. I'll post a snippet of the value for data above where I can format it for easier reading. I'm not quite sure what to make of that though.

Comment: Sorry, didn't follow up on your question. I have updated the answer. Somehow i overlooked you jsp.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the issue is the way input path variable declared.

```
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="selectedUser.firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="selectedUser.firstName"></form:input></td>
</tr>
```

You don't have to mention selectedUser as Spring knows how to bind the data. Spring can bind the values to properties of model attributes. If it could not find any, it just ignores them. Hence you were getting empty object always, as Spring will instantiate new object.

```
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="firstName"></form:input></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I did try that, however the bound object is of type UserData, which contains a User object whose instance name is selected user so that syntax is required. Here's the error I get when I remove it: 'org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'username' of bean class [org.softwarewolf.gameserver.base.repository.domain.UserData]: Bean property 'username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter'.

Comment: Sure. I will connect you through email @ the address above. Its becoming quite interesting now.